# knockout modal window opens only once

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal window which opens on button click. Everything works fine except one thing : when i click on outmodal space - modal window become closed but i can open it again on button click. If i close modal on button close - it works well.

**Update**: when i close modal using 'Esc' keyboard - behaviour is the same as for outmodal click.

---

## HTML

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { $root.showLogModal(); }" title="Show Logs" class="btn btn-large btn-info">Show Logs</button>

<div data-bind="bootstrapLogModal: logModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
```

## Custom Template

```
<script id="showLogModal" type="text/html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click: close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Logs</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      Some Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: close">Close</button>
</div>
```

## JS

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.logModal = {
        show: ko.observable(false),

        onClose: function () {
        },
        onAction: function () {
        }
    };

    self.showLogModal = function () {
        self.logModal.show(true);
    };
}

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapLogModal = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, bindingContext) {
            var props = valueAccessor(),
                vm = bindingContext.createChildContext(data);
            ko.utils.extend(vm, props);
            vm.close = function () {
                vm.show(false);
                vm.onClose();
            };
            vm.action = function () {
                vm.onAction();
            };
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, "modal hide fade large", true);
            ko.renderTemplate("showLogModal", vm, null, element);
            var showHide = ko.computed(function () {
                $(element).modal(vm.show() ? 'show' : 'hide');
            });
            return {
                controlsDescendantBindings: true
            };
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

---

### http://jsfiddle.net/tLT6d/ here is Live example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected behavior, if you want to prevent the modal closing when outside area is click, provide `backdrop` attribute as `'static'`.

```
Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify static for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.
```

## update

I don't know why you rewrite the bootstrap modal into knockout, but to make you code works without closing the modal when outside area is clicked.
just add this line of code  in your binding handler

```
ko.renderTemplate("showLogModal", vm, null, element);
// adds new code
$(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', show: false });
var showHide = ko.computed(function () {
   $(element).modal(vm.show() ? 'show' : 'hide');
});
```

## update 2

To fix your initial code to perform proper closing, when outside area is clicked, attach hidden event handler and call the related close method.

```
// adds new code
$(element).on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
   vm.close();
});
var showHide = ko.computed(function () {
   $(element).modal(vm.show() ? 'show' : 'hide');
});
```

Comment: thank you for reply. Yes i read about it, but what about case allow user to close modal by click outside of modal area but also to open it again?

Comment: thanks again. But i want to close it on outside click. and open it again. this is my problem. And about `I don't know why you rewrite the bootstrap modal into knockout` - i just start to work with knockout and bootstrap, so i use existing code on the project. But you can advice better solution :)

Comment: @user3770925, see my update, in my opinion you dont have to create a bootstrap wrapper handler for just show and hide the modal, you can just use normal `Static example` in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript)

Comment: Second Update help) Thanks